# How do I configure Postgresql on Windows 8.1 to connect to Golang?

Tags: windows-8, postgresql

I'm trying to follow the tutorial here: https://gophercasts.io/lessons/4-postgres-basics but I'm having problems with the way in which the user is set up in Windows 8.1 (64-bit).

The tutorial has a data.sql which is a script to create some seed data for the purposes of the tutorial but when I try and run it through the command line I get this error:

> createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  password
>   authentication failed for user "user"

The command I ran was :

> C:\code\gocode>createdb lesson4

My Windows account is just called 'user'. Also when I open pgadmin3 the only Postgresql account I see is called 'postgres'.

How do I set up an account so I can run commands from the command-line?

(Apologies in advance if this is the incorrect forum, I wasn't sure if I should post it here, or Stackoverflow or DBA Stackexchange, please do not punish me with downvotes, just let me know if I should get it moved elsewhere)

Comment: You have to allow access through your [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file. This may involve creating a database user too. If the link doesn't help, post the contents of your pg_hba.conf file.

Answer (score -1):

Create a windows user account called 'postgres' with a password  'postgres'(or whatever password you set for your postgres server). then run your script again. Make sure you have admin priviledges too.

In fact if you are using window rather install pgAdmin and user the graphic user interface to create the database and run the script. It will save a lot of time.

http://www.pgadmin.org/download/windows.php

Comment: I mentioned in my post that that account is already there. I did try and use the pgadmin interface, but there is an underlying problem because when I try and run the Golang script I get more errors which I believe are related to these user accounts. Basically, using pgadmin works but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Tried with admin privileges, same error :(